# MakeFile @cd print message in console

Tags: c, makefile, cd

Into my Makefile I have some command that redirect into others makefiles and to do that, I need cd command. But I don't know why or where it defined that everytime I use `@cd` in my Makefile a message is printed into the console as : 
 *" We enter into the repertory " blabla/toto "*

My Makefile is simple, here's the code :

```
TARGETS=$(shell ls -d programme*)
CLEANTARGETS=$(foreach dir,$(TARGETS),clean_$(dir))

all: $(TARGETS) 

.PHONY: $(TARGETS) $(CLEANTARGETS)
$(TARGETS) :
   @echo "Execution de make $@ :\n"
   @cd $@; make

$(CLEANTARGETS) :
  @echo -n "Execution de clean $(subst clean_,,$@)\n" :
  @cd $(subst clean_,,$@); make clean

clean: $(CLEANTARGETS)
```

This makefile redirect into 2 others Makefiles but they don't use cd command , and the code is very simple , so I don't think it's relevant to show you it.

**EDIT** :

My problem is I just don't want it to print , it's too messy after , I just want the makefile to do cd without printing anything

Here are the full printed message :

> Execution de make programme1 :

> make[1] : on entre dans le répertoire « ~/Shortest-Path/programme1 »

> Production de programme1.exe à partir des fichiers : programme1.c treatmentFiles.c treatmentFiles.h

> gcc -Wall programme1.c treatmentFiles.c treatmentFiles.h -o programme1.exe

> Le programme programme1.exe a été produit dans le répertoire programme1

> make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « ~/Shortest-Path/programme1 »

So, the others line are normally printed with my echo command , but don't know why cd command print

> on entre dans le répertoire « ~/Shortest-Path/programme1 »

and

> on quitte dans le répertoire « ~/Shortest-Path/programme1 »

Any help or Advice is welcome !

Comment: What exactly is the problem with that message?

Comment: Please cut and paste exact commands you entered and exact errors you got.  Paraphrasing with "blabla" just means we can't help you because we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: But, maybe you want to look at this info from the GNU make manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/_002dw-Option.html

Comment: I just edited to be more clear about the problem, which is I don't know why the cd command , print on console  a message, I don't jnow where this was defined, definitely not on my code...

Comment: thanks @MadScientist , I didn't know such an option existed , it works well when I run make --no-print-directory , but do you know how to automatically turn it on ? on the code of the makefile and not directly on the CLI ?

Comment: You could also consider `make -C $@`. This would make it clear that the CWD should be unchanged after the line is executed.

Comment: You can set `MAKEFLAGS`, discussed here: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options_002fRecursion.html

Comment: The cd command is not to blame; the message is produced by Make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is to add this option :

> MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory